# which rendering way should I use in a web based project

Tags: html, raytracing, processing.js

I have a database of 3D models. I want user can rotate the model and view it in the web page.
So I have to implement an instant rendering algorithm for this.

A raytracing/raycasting method on CPU is preferred since the server has no GPU on it.

I understand that a primary-ray-only ray tracer with SSE and KD-Tree/BVH can be very fast. Besides, I want to add some GI effect(fake GI effect can be also OK for me, such as SSAO) in it.

How good can I achieve?

(some NPR rendering methods are also considerable)

Comment: "since the server has no GPU on it" - I don't see how that's relevant, since you'd be doing WebGL, which is entirely client-based.

Comment: I think 3d models are stored on the server and webgl can not make use of it without downloading the vertex of models to client side(Am I correct?). As a result I want to do rendering on server.

Comment: If you want to render 3D objects in real-time without sending the vertices to the client, you want to do something that's (nearly) impossible, since it requires a real-time video stream from the server to the client.

Comment: What you want to do is technically possible (though, everything is technically possible) but it's not an easy thing to pull off; hell it took onlive six years to develop, essentially, what you're asking for. Is there some reason you can't download the model and render client-side?

Comment: @ceprovence: The reason behind this is most likely to keep others from grabbing the models and using them for their own personal use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5, you can render 3D objects with WebGL (an implementation of OpenGL) with some JavaScript. The problem is that WebGL is a client technology. Therefore, all the rendering is done by the browser.

There is one possible solution if you really want to distribute some logic on a server. You could use a server side language and send the vertices to the client through some database transactions. After, your website could make some AJAX calls to a server that would make certain operations within the server and return some vertices. The only problem is that this could require a lot of bandwidth.

Otherwise, another solution would be to use a tool such as [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) to create what you want. Then, you would need to embed the Unity Player in your web page.